# Filtering a Future Optional list

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say we have a DAO method getUserById and it gives back a `Future<Optional<User>>`. This User object has a list of friends.

Now, I would like to filter the friend list like this: 
`public Future<List<Optional<User>>> filterFriendsBySomething(){}`

That means the main method calls `filterFriendsBySomething()` which calls `getUserById()` from a map operation and execution of the future list is happening within the main method.

Is it even possible or maybe I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Seems to be overly complicated. Just return a `Future<List<User>>`.

Comment: You're essentially delving into the world of reactive programming without a reactive library, which is going to be cumbersome, to say the least. Have a look at RxJava/Akka/Reactor. In Reactor for example, your `Future<Optional<User>>` becomes just `Mono<User>`, and you have powerful built in map/filter operations on that object.

Comment: Sure, I would use AKKA in production. But I just had an interview with this problem and I just wanted to see the solution.

Comment: The answer to the question asked at the end would always be to give it a try and you would find one way or the other. Theoretically creating a `Future<List<Optional<User>>>` does seem impossible, but then trying it out would reflect if you really need it.

Comment: How about Future<List<User>>, would that be possible?